# Is there a way to get user's speech input as text from the AWS Lex interactive voice view in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

In my activity, I have code that implements the onResponse method of the AWS InteractiveVoiceListener like so:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(final Response response){
     String responseString = response.getTextResponse();
...
```

From this, I can only get the bot's response as text. 
Question is, how do I get the user's speech as text before or after it is sent to Lex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API is available in AWS SDK for Android version 2.4.2

`response.getInputTranscript()`